# Firebase Auth: Multiple apps, Sign in with Apple

Tags: firebase-authentication, sign-in-with-apple

We're having problem signing in with Apple with our setup.

We have an education platform with 50 or so different apps/product.

All apps have their own separate Firebase project, but they share the same Firebase Project for authentication, so the user can login with the same account on all the apps.

**Basic setup:**

- 1 Firebase project for all authentications
- Separate Firebase project for all individual apps.

**What works**

Facebook Auth and Email Auth worked right out of the box, and after putting each separate projects Client Id in the auth project 
"Whitelist client IDs from external projects", Google Auth worked too.

**The problem**

The problem is with Sign In With Apple. We can get one of the projects to work by adding the apps Bundle ID to the 
"Service ID (not required for iOS)" in the Auth projects Authentication/Apple section. 
But this field only accept one Bundle ID (compared to Google Auth Whitelist, who accept multiple), and we get an error when trying to sign in:

> The audience in ID Token [com.BUNDLE.ID.HERE.XXX] does not match the expected audience

Any suggestion on what to do would be very appreciated.

Comment: Same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: Any update on this? Got stuck by the same issue :/

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a service ID with bundle name com.bundle, and make sure it's associated with a common app ID.

Comment: Could you expand on this please?